# How to two-way bind the ViewModel with CheckBoxes?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, checkbox

I have a user admin tool that edits permissions for users. I have the admin select checkboxes at the application.

The permissions can be different from server to server. Right now I just have static checkboxes and its real nasty.

I'm trying to figure out how to create some kind of dynamic scheme for the checkboxes and track when they have been checked / unchecked.

When the user selects the checkboxes I could just search through the object and make the changes to the database.

Well at least that's the way I have thought of it so far. Does anyone have any input or maybe an example of something like this in action ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx), bind its [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) to a collection of VMs which represent a permission. In the [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) you can create a `CheckBox` whose `IsChecked` is bound to a property on your item VM which represents the state of that permission.

You then can get all the states from the source collection's objects.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume there are the following user permissions:

```
[Flags]
public enum UserPermissions
{
    Administrator = 0x1,
    BackupOperator = 0x2,
    PowerUser = 0x4,
    User = 0x8,
    Guest = 0x10
}
```

Enum members should be data bound to the checkboxes.

Okay, it will be `ListBox` with `CheckBox` items:

1) `CheckBox` class has boolean `IsChecked` property, but it can't be bound directly to flags enumeration.

2) `ListBox` class has `ItemsSource` property which can be bound to collection.

So, it is necessary to convert the flags enumeration to List of flag ViewModels:

1) Create ViewModel which represents **single** flag. Let's call it `UserPermissionViewModel` class. It should have `IsChecked` boolean and the **single enum flag value** `Permission` properties.

```
public class UserPermissionViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public UserPermissionViewModel(UserPermissions permission, bool isSet)
    {
        Permission = permission;
        IsSet = isSet;
    }

    public UserPermissions Permission { get; private set; }

    public bool IsSet { get; set; }
}
```

2) Create ViewModel for all flags (contains many instances of UserPermissionViewModel class). Let's call it `UserPermissionsViewModel` class. This ViewModel should take the source enum in constructor and convert it to internal collection of its flags representation: collection of `UserPermissionViewModel` instances. Also there should be `Result` property which will return the **flags enum** using `IsChecked` property values of `UserPermissionViewModel` instances.

```
public class UserPermissionsViewModel
{
    public UserPermissionsViewModel(UserPermissions permissions)
    {
        // Convert each flag of UserPermissions enum to UserPermissionViewModel and pass IsSet (true) if the permissions has the flag.
        Permissions = allPermissions.Select(singlePermission => new UserPermissionViewModel(singlePermission, permissions.HasFlag(singlePermission))).ToList();
    }

    public List<UserPermissionViewModel> Permissions
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public UserPermissions Result
    {
        get
        {
            // Iterate over Permissions list and get result flags enum.
        }
    }
```

3) Create `ListBox` in the View, bind it to permission list property of `UserPermissionsViewModel` class. `ListBox` should contain `CheckBox` and `TextBlock` as `ItemTemplate`. Bind them to `IsChecked` and `Permission` properties accordingly.

After that, the binding should work, the result can be taken using `Result` property.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PermissionsViewModel.Permissions}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <WrapPanel>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSet}" />
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Permission}" />
      </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I would not suggest a `ListBox` as it introduces selection which is not needed, a normal `ItemsControl` should do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any code, but maybe some variations you could use:

- Create a set of check boxes and make them visible/invisible as you need them. Preferably if you only have a max. fixed amount.
- Create a list of check boxes, create them dynamically and set an observer (event) to listen to changes (IsChecked).
- Don't use checkboxes but a listview or listbox with checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

An example of what H.B. says above:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Privileges}">
        <ItemsControl .ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Privilege}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl .ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl >
```

Comment: See the comment on Serge's answer.